# Dapper. What Exceptions does conn.Execute throw?

Tags: c#, exception, dapper

I'm using dapper.net and I've wrapped `connection.Execute` for my `Delete` and `Update` statements.

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    IDbConnection connection = connectionService.Connection;

    connection.Execute(UpdateQuery, entity, connectionService.Transaction);
}
```

When I've come to use this, I want to know if it fails or not by catching an exception(s) and not just a general `Exception`. Which (if any) exceptions are thrown? I would assume `SqlException`, but a previous manager taught me to assume nothing.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to where I find this information?

Comment: If connectionService.Connection returns a SqlConnection then my answer below is correct. I have search for some online documentation but it is scarce (hence why you ended up here). I know this from practice as I have been using dapper as you want to just this week :)

Comment: Dapper doesn't mask any exceptions. If your database provider is SQL, it will throw a `SqlException`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dapper will indeed throw `SqlException` when used against a SqlConnection.

The exceptions will be consistent with those that you will get from vanilla ADO.NET code. With a value that is the code of the specific SQL exception type.

Comment: Nice, but can I use DbException instead? I do not want to bring System.Data.SqlClient package to the code

Comment: SqlException is derived from DbException so you should be able to catch on just DbException.